# UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xef' when I load npy file on Google Colab

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory

There is a .npy file which I am trying to load in google colab notebook, this same file when I loaded in my Jupyter Notebook it worked well without issues but in colab I am facing this issue:

```
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding, max_header_size)
    440             try:
--> 441                 return pickle.load(fid, **pickle_kwargs)
    442             except Exception as e:

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xef'.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding, max_header_size)
    441                 return pickle.load(fid, **pickle_kwargs)
    442             except Exception as e:
--> 443                 raise pickle.UnpicklingError(
    444                     print("Hello world")
    445                     f"Failed to interpret file {file!r} as a pickle") from e

UnpicklingError: Failed to interpret file '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/ground_truth.npy' as a pickle
```

and the script which I am running is:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sci
from google.colab import drive
```

```
a = np.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/ground_truth.npy', encoding='bytes', allow_pickle=True)
```

When I let `allow_pickle=False` I got:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-fd12baa39e9b> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 a = np.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/ground_truth.npy', encoding='bytes')

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding, max_header_size)
    436             # Try a pickle
    437             if not allow_pickle:
--> 438                 raise ValueError("Cannot load file containing pickled data "
    439                                  "when allow_pickle=False")
    440             try:

ValueError: Cannot load the file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False
```

I am using Python version 3.10.12 with numpy version 1.23.5 on Google Colab and in Jupyter Notebook Python version 3.9.13 with numpy version 1.24.3

Comment: most likely a file corruption issue

Comment: Weird, because in Jupyter Notebook it's running normally only in google colab i'm facing this issue

Comment: You have to use `allow_pickle=False` on the `save`, NOT on the `load`.

Comment: That's all the more reason to suspect the corruption issue.  It's messed up, in some way or other, during the transfer from the notebook environment to the colab.